# Android Game Save and Load doesn't work

Tags: unity, 2d, android, single-player

I tried a few different codes but none of them work on my android device...I retrieve the data with this command " GameManager.Instance.gemsToSave"

The code:

```
     public static GameManager Instance { get; private set; }

     public float highscoreToSave;
     public int coinsToSave;
     public int gemsToSave;

     private void Awake()
     {
         if (Instance == null)
         {
             Instance = this;
             DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
         }
         else if(Instance != this)
         {
             Destroy(gameObject);
         }
     }
     private void OnEnable()
     {
         Load();
     }
     private void OnDisable()
     {
         Save();
     }
     public void Save()
     {
         BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
         FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat");
         PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
         data.highScore = highscoreToSave;
         data.coins = coinsToSave;
         data.gems = gemsToSave;

         bf.Serialize(file, data);
         file.Close();
     }
     public void Load()
     {
         if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
         {
             BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
             FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);
             PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
             file.Close();
             highscoreToSave = data.highScore;
             coinsToSave = data.coins;
             gemsToSave = data.gems;
         }
     }
    }

[Serializable] 
class PlayerData {

public float highScore;
public int coins;
public int gems;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I remember I had troubles with android when it comes to writing to files. Not sure what the proper solution is, but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with permissions. In my case when I initialised the writing to a file, the function would never return on android (but it would work perfectly on other platforms). Have you tried using `PlayerPrefs` instead? If I'm not wrong, when compiled for android they are using android's native ways to save data, so you don't have to bother with permissions (since every app is allowed to save data this way).